# Play Video with least memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play video file in my bundle and am using repeat mode as `MPMovieRepeatModeOne`. During the video playing time it's take huge memory 50mb during the run time. Please help me in resolving the issue .Which is consuming a very large issue . And the consumed memory got once the  video player removed

---

---

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ConnectorAnimation.mp4" ofType:nil];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    mediaPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    mediaPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    mediaPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [_contentView addSubview:mediaPlayer.view];
    CGRect frame = _contentView.bounds;
    mediaPlayer.view.frame = frame;

    mediaPlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [mediaPlayer play];
```

Comment: Are you playing video over and over again and is this memory leak occurs in first play or later? perhaps [mediaPlayer removeFromSuperview] when complated to play can help.

Comment: am using repeat mode one so during play time memory got increased after that it was released